# Windows machine constantly hammered by logon attempts

Tags: windows-10, security

It looks like my home PC is under a constant barrage of log-on attempts from different IP addresses on the Internet.  I use a strong pass-phrase but I'd still like to block them.

Example log event:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}" /> 
  <EventID>4625</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12544</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-10-07T03:27:48.349868200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>172146</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{d6713e20-6fee-0000-5d3e-71d6ee6fd501}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="800" ThreadID="23308" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyPC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">ADMINISTRATOR</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetDomainName" /> 
  <Data Name="Status">0xc000006d</Data> 
  <Data Name="FailureReason">%%2313</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubStatus">0xc000006a</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonType">3</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonProcessName">NtLmSsp</Data> 
  <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">NTLM</Data> 
  <Data Name="WorkstationName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="LmPackageName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="KeyLength">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">193.188.22.122</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Please advise.

**Edit:**

I have RDP enabled on a non-standard port and it is forwarded on the router.
Currently I have blocked the IP ranges of the subnets those attacks were coming from using the Windows built-in firewall, but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Your Windows version has a firewall; have you already tried activating it?

Comment: You should stick your PC behind a router if it isn’t. It is rare to see this behavior and suggests you are using only one internet connected device in your house or you have something really hooked up or configured wrong. You should provide information about your ISP equipment, any additional routers you have and how many devices you have and how they are connecting to the internet. Did you turn on port forwarding for some reason?

Comment: @Appleoddity, yes, edited question.

Comment: That’s the way it is. If you open up RDP on your router it is going to be attacked day in and day out. Use a VPN or some other remote access technology like team viewer. Otherwise that is the risk you take. Most security consultants would advise against opening RDP to the world.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about those attempts don't forward RDP and expose it to the internet. By doing so this is going to happen. It's not unusual and just something you have to live with. Setting up a VPN or restricting access in some other way might be preferable. It's only been a short while since there was CVE for a wormable remote execution vulnerability for RDP.

You already did setup blocks and you could try to automate it. A simple option would be to use PowerShell to read your EventLog and act on it or looking for a fail2ban Windows alternative. Depending on your router you might also be able to implement the blocks on it or to setup some solution that allows you quickly enable/disable the forward.